# An invisible giant on a steamship

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read this story at least 20 years ago, probably in a collection so it could be even older.

The POV character works on a steamship, mostly in the engine room. He befriends a very old man who also works there, although the work is very hard, involving throwing coal by the spadeful into the furnace. But the old man does it and does not seem to suffer from this task.
The old man explains to the POV character that he has "help". A very powerful invisible giant, possibly an alien, who feeds on the heat of the furnace.

I forgot most of the details. I vaguely remember that the  ship gets caught in a hurricane and capsizes but I am not sure.